# Кликабельное изображение в Camera slideshow, цепляющее ссылку из "url A" в материале

Tags: php, joomla, slider

Больше половины дня бьюсь над этим вопросом, хотя всё, вроде как, просто и ответ где-то рядом.

Задача - в баннере Camera Slideshow сделать кликабельными изображения, причём ссылка должна подхватываться из "url A" в материале. В файле **_item.php** изображение цепляется строкой

```
<div class="camera-item" data-src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>">
```

урл заранее объявил

```
<?php $urls = json_decode($item->urls); ?>
```

И в отдельности всё работает

```
<a href='<?php echo $urls->urla;?>'>Урл А</a>
```

Сам пока что новичок и как всё это собрать в кучу - не могу сообразить о_О Заранее спасибо за помощь! и плюсов в карму всем откликнувшимся.

Comment: Добавлю, что при стандартной постановке '<a href="..."><div>...</div></a>' ловится ошибка и вместо главной страницы выдаётся пустая с 1 лишь строчкой в коде '<div id="camera-slideshow" class="camera_wrap" style="height: 755px;">'